# Getting the current domain name in Chrome when the page fails to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

If you try to load with Chrome: http://sdqdsqdqsdsqdsqd.com/

You'll obtain:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I would like, with a bookmarklet, to be able to get the current domain name and redirect it to a whois page in order to check if the domain is available.

I tried in the console:

```
window.location.href
```

but it outputs:

```
"data:text/html,chromewebdata"
```

Is there any way to retrieve the failed URL?

Comment: These days, chrome console outputs `"chrome-error://chromewebdata/"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solutions given by others didn't work (maybe because I was getting a different error or have a newer version: Chrome 55):

```
document.querySelector('strong[jscontent="hostName"]').textContent
```

but the same can be achieved via:

```
document.querySelector('#reload-button').url
```

A potentially more future-proof version (from [Thomas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989031/getting-the-current-domain-name-in-chrome-when-the-page-fails-to-load#comment63159072_29989150))

```
loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl
```

So a cross-version solution incorporating all workarounds:

```
var url = (l‌​ocation.href === 'data‌​:text/html,chromeweb‌​data'
    && loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl
    || document.querySelector('#reload-button').url
) || location.href;

var hostname = (l‌​ocation.href === 'data‌​:text/html,chromeweb‌​data'
    && loadTimeData.data_.summary.hostName
    || document.querySelector('strong[jscontent="hostName"]').textContent
) || location.hostname;
```

Answer (score 3):

On the Chrome error page, `location.href` doesn't point to the domain you tried to visit, since it's an internally-hosted page.

However, the domain name you tried to visit is available if you expand the "Show Details" link.

You can run this code in console (or a bookmarklet) to parse out the domain name:

```
document.querySelector('strong[jscontent="hostName"]').textContent
```

Comment: Very clever, how could I miss this!

Comment: Unfortunately, this only exposes the host name, not the full URL.

Comment: @chbrown, this is what I used to get full url (chrome only, but my use case was in a chrome bookmark): `location.href==="data:text/html,chromewebdata"&&loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl||location.href`

Comment: And FWIW, this is the full bookmark - loads page from the Wayback Machine: `javascript:void(location.href='http://web.archive.org/*/'+(location.href==="data:text/html,chromewebdata"&&loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl||location.href))`

Answer (score 2):

A modified version of nderscore's since you'll need to have an if statement for the return of the correct one.

```
   function getUrl () {
     if(window.location.hostname == "") {
       return document.querySelector('strong[jscontent="hostName"]').textContent
     } else{
       return window.location.href;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Most complete answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While looking in source code of html page using Developer Tools (right-click on a web page, and select Inspect Element), I've found that full original failed URL is in a variable called

`loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl`

In my case I have to update some 'incorrect part' of auto generated URL to 'correct part'. So I've created bookmarlet like this:

```
javascript: location.assign(loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl.replace('IncorrectPart','CorrectPart'));
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. But `loadTimeData.data_.summary.failedUrl` seems to print the correct url that orignally failed.